# Proguard removed Facebook Sdk Share Dialog Content

Tags: android, facebook, proguard, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-share

I am using proguard with my android project.
Whenever i open a share dialog of Facebook for Android it gets empty.

facebook sdk version is 3.23.1

```
if(FacebookDialog.canPresentShareDialog(thisObj, FacebookDialog.ShareDialogFeature.SHARE_DIALOG)){
    OpenGraphObject object = OpenGraphObject.Factory.createForPost("namespace:"+obj.object);
    object.setProperty("title", obj.title);
    object.setProperty("image", obj.image);
    object.setProperty("url", obj.url);
    object.setProperty("description", obj.description);
    OpenGraphAction action = GraphObject.Factory.create(OpenGraphAction.class);
    action.setType("namespace:"+obj.action);
    action.setProperty(obj.object, object);
    FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.OpenGraphActionDialogBuilder(thisObj, action, obj.object).build();
    fbUiLifecycleHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
}
```

this code works perfect when using it without proguard, everything is shared easily, i also submitted Key Hashes on Facebook correctly for different signatures used.

*Whenever i use Proguard obuscation, I get empty title, image or description in the sharedialog, all data gets lost and sometimes it says error and sometimes closes without error*

-keep class com.facebook.** { *; }

-keepattributes Signature

i also used many proguard tags including these ones, but the only case when the share dialog works perfectly is when i disable obfuscation by tag "-dontobfuscate".

Hope somebody had similar issue and can help me.

Sometimes log displays errors like Serialization error, i also tried many codes from proguard official site, like the following but this never solved the issues, its been 2 days since i am searching questions on stackoverflow and compiled the apk file using various proguard options.

```
-keepnames class * implements java.io.Serializable

-keepclassmembernames class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}
```

Comment: The Facebook sdks says you do not need to perform any extra steps: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started#proguard.

Comment: @JaredBurrows a day before today the facebook page displayed this

-keep class com.facebook.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature

Comment: If you use the latest 4.0.0 SDK, you won't need to take any special steps any more.

Comment: @GokhanCaglar i use eclipse and facebook provided guide for only android studio, can you help in importing it to eclipse.

Comment: See if this works: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/gradle-integration-eclipse-44

Comment: Thanks for the help, but according to google Eclipse support will end soon, i am trying to use the new Android Studio IDE and using the new facebook sdk 4.0.0 built on gradle, i will post the update whether the share dialog and proguard works or not after changing the fb integration to new code according to the new sdk(will update the question after that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Older Facebook Sdk was giving errors with proguard.
Now the new Facebook Sdk versions 4.0.0 and 4.0.1 are not giving any errors with proguard.
But for using the new sdk i have updated the following
1) Eclipse is not officially supported by Android so migrated to Android Studio.
2) used the facebook sdk as a Gradle Dependency not as a project(like we did in Eclipse or older versions of sdk). No need to import any project, just add this line to gradle depedencies

```
compile "com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.1"
```

thats it, after these changes proguard worked smoothly without errors, but surely i had a lot of migration issues. Good Luck